# How do we get a question unmarked as duplicate?

Tags: discussion, support

This question [How to oil/treat a solid beech table top that will be used as a computer desk? [duplicate]](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/2244/how-to-oil-treat-a-solid-beech-table-top-that-will-be-used-as-a-computer-desk/2252#2252) was marked as a duplicate of [How do I prepare and take care of a wooden countertop?](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/1074/how-do-i-prepare-and-take-care-of-a-wooden-countertop)

While they were similar topics, they were substantially different, requiring and receiving different sets of answers.  The original question was asking about finishing a counter top, a surface in which moisture resistance is an absolute requirement. The question marked as a duplicate was simply for a desk or table top for which preventing water damage is not a high priority.

Clearly not duplicates.

How do we go about requesting the removal of the duplicate mark?

Answer (score 1):

The way to get a question unmarked as a duplicate is exactly what you've done--bring it up in meta.

That said, to me the second question (about a desk) should have been closed as unclear because it is asking multiple questions and the title doesn't match the body.

Ignoring that, the body of the desk question seems to be more about the proper method of applying boiled linseed oil rather than determining an appropriate type of finish.  (And if it were the latter, we might already have a question about appropriate finish for a desk...I'd have to check.)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to asking on meta, if you have enough rep to vote-to-close/reopen you can simply vote to re-open.  It will be added to a queue at that point where others will likely look at it and decide if they agree (and I'd post a comment on the Q as to why I think it's not a duplicate, if it's appropriate).

This matters more on sites that have more traffic than this really - here a meta post is perfectly reasonable, since there won't be all that many of them.

Comment: That said - I think it's a reasonable duplicate.  There's just not that much difference between the two that you really need two questions, unless the other one is specific (maybe, "Do I need to treat a computer desktop in the same way I would a kitchen countertop" type question, if it's specifically getting at that; if it's just "how do I oil a wooden somethingoranother", it's sufficient to be a duplicate I think).

Comment: How can we consider the questions to be duplicates when they evoke distinctly different answers?

Comment: To me those are not particularly different questions, and the difference in answer comes from the answerers reading context into the question that's not there.  Perhaps it should be there, but, it's not.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. My basic question has been answered and we are to point of beating a dead horse.

Comment: Agree.  (Now, go vote to reopen that question if you believe it should be!)